# how to use session_start() properly on GoDaddy site

Tags: php, session, post

**Fix Below** My problem had nothing to do with headers having "already been sent". That was simply a symptom of the problem. The **problem ended up being a sever side issue with GoDaddy** as a folder was missing on their end.

I have edited my question's name to include "GoDaddy site" to maybe help someone in the future having the same issue.

Per @KennyPowers suggestion I called Go Daddy. I originally had a windows hosted account and switched to linux. Apparently the folder that `session_start()` saves to by default did not migrate with the rest of my site, and no you cant change the default folder..at least not on my site.

GoDaddy replaced the folder on their end and everything works fine now

---

**Original Question:**

I could use a little help using **session_start()**

**Site flow:**

- **page1.html** has a form which **POSTs to page2.php**
- **page2.php** does some stuff with the data and presents a **link to
  page3.php**
- when **page3.php** loads it also **needs** to do something with **the data from
  the form**

All pages are on the same domain so Im trying to do this with session_start()

This is what Ive tried:

### **Page 2:**

```
<?php
// page2.php

session_start();

echo 'Welcome to page #2';

$_SESSION["guest1Last"] = $_POST["guest1Last"];
$_SESSION["guest1First"] = $_POST["guest1First"];
$_SESSION["guest1Middle"] = $_POST ["guest1Middle"];

?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
// more HTML and PHP stuff down here
```

### **Page 3:**

```
<?php
// page3.php

session_start();

echo 'Welcome to page #3<br />';


echo $_SESSION["guest1First"];  
echo $_SESSION["guest1Middle"];
echo $_SESSION["guest1Last"]; 

?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
// more HTML and PHP stuff down here
```

**These are the warnings I get when page 2 loads:**
(same thing on page3)

---

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/var/chroot/home/content/08/10125908/tmp/sess_3dt4c7etqd6hr28dls0bludiv4, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/content/08/10125908/html/_php/page2.php on line 4

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/08/10125908/html/_php/page2.php:4) in /home/content/08/10125908/html/_php/page2.php on line 4

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/08/10125908/html/_php/page2.php:4) in /home/content/08/10125908/html/_php/page2.php on line 4
Welcome to page #2





Warning: Unknown: open(/var/chroot/home/content/08/10125908/tmp/sess_3dt4c7etqd6hr28dls0bludiv4, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct () in Unknown on line 0
```

The  ***"headers already sent"*** part makes me think session_start() is not in the right place on the page but its at the top where I believe it should be. That said it seams likely that   "***No such file or directory***" is where the problem is starting, for obvious reasons. I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the direction of what i am doing wrong.

**EDIT**

---

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('session.save_path', '/var/chroot/home/content/08/10125908/html/tmp');
echo 'Welcome to page #1';

$_SESSION["guest1Last"] = $_POST["guest1Last"];
$_SESSION["guest1First"] = $_POST["guest1First"];
$_SESSION["guest1Middle"] = $_POST ["guest1Middle"];



?>
```

- I created a folder tmp and gave it all permissions
- I added `ini_set('session.save_path',
  '/var/chroot/home/content/08/10125908/html/tmp');`
- and tried ini_set('session.save_path', 'html/tmp');
- I also created a text file with
  `session_save_path('/home/content/04/8260904/html/tmp');`  saved it
  as **php.ini** and uploaded it to my root
- I also I also created a text file with
  `session_save_path('/home/content/04/8260904/html/tmp');`  saved it
  as **php5.ini** and uploaded it to my root

Im still getting the same error

```
 Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/var/chroot/home/content/08/10125908/tmp/sess_3659a32a50e33e5f918a9e39d70a1668, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory
```

am I not setting the folder destination correctly?

---

**My folder setup now**
[image]

Per @KennyPowers suggestion I called Go Daddy. I originally had a windows hosted account and switched to linux. Apparently that folder did not migrate with the rest of my site, and no you cant change the default folder..at least not on my site.

Comment: I saw that post in searching but I cant see in my code where output could be generated before I call **session_start();** as was the case there, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that you don't have tmp. The first error says about that:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/var/chroot/home/content/08/10125908/tmp/sess_3dt4c7etqd6hr28dls0bludiv4, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/content/08/10125908/html/_php/page2.php on line 4
```

That's why the session can't start. See "**...failed: No such file or directory (2) in..**"

You need to create `/var/chroot/home/content/08/10125908/tmp/` and set read/write permission on that directory.
You can change session temp direcotry by using the next function from your php script:

```
ini_set('session.save_path', '/session/directory/goes/here');
```

The warnings you get after this one tell you that there was some data sent back to your browser - which was actually the first warning text. It will be fixed right after you fix tmp directory issue.

Comment: This is definitely the problem thank you, Im trying to change the destination folder as you suggested but am having problems would you mind taking a look at my edit?

Comment: is that your local machine or hosting server? can you do `print phpinfo();` and see if session.save_path has been changed or not? you said that you set up `session_save_path` in php.ini, but the name of it is wrong. `session.save_path` -- the right one, there's a comma after 'session'

Comment: if it's hosting machine then you probably need to contact you hosting provider about that. You probably are not allowed to do chance this value.

Comment: gotcha, yeah I tried it with both `session.save_path` and `session_save_path` cause I saw `session_save_path` somewhere else online and thought it was worth a shot. Its a hosted site so I guess im calling them, thank you for your help!!

Comment: never dream of it :P, Thanks again!

Comment: In my case, the path had a html in it. So with your example, it was `/var/chroot/home/content/08/10125908/html/tmp/`

Answer (score 1):

The directory PHP is attempting to use to store session information either does not exist or is not writeable.

The directory in question is:

`/var/chroot/home/content/08/10125908/tmp/`

This location is set in `PHP.ini` as `session.save_path`.

You need to ensure this directory exists and is writeable by the user PHP is running under.

Comment: good there they are the first 5 characters no spaces or anything else first

Comment: thats it for sure, I cant seem to change the destination folder correctly though. Would you mind taking a look at my edit?

Comment: In my case, the path had a html in it. So with your example, it was `/var/chroot/home/content/08/10125908/html/tmp/`

Answer (score 1):

PHP has problems writing data into the session files. You should check your session settings and verify that the necessary permissions are set on the file system side.

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/var/chroot/home/content/08/10125908/tmp/sess_3dt4c7etqd6hr28dls0bludiv4, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/content/08/10125908/html/_php/page2.php on line 4
```

regarding the **headers already sent** error: due to your error reporting level a warning was generated while trying to write the session data. This auto-generated warning is the trigger for the headers already sent error.
Fix the permission issue and it should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You probally have some ountput before the `session_start();` please check for any text (including spaces before `session_start();`. It should be the first in your document.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that PHP sessions are currently not working on your server and the cookie cannot be set. The PHP server is not allowing the session to start and the error is how you find out.
The error is telling you that it cannot open the required session temporary folder because the folder does not exist.

Please check this link:
[http://tclayson.com/2012/03/08/how-to-fix-error-warning-session_start-function-session-start-openpathtofile-o_rdwr-failed-permission-denied-13-in-pathtoscript-php-on-line-**line**-2/](http://tclayson.com/2012/03/08/how-to-fix-error-warning-session_start-function-session-start-openpathtofile-o_rdwr-failed-permission-denied-13-in-pathtoscript-php-on-line-__line__-2/)

Comment: that is the problem but the link you posted doesnt seem to be all that related