# array_push not adding 2nd item after page refresh

Tags: php, array-push

I understand that array_push is not adding a 2nd item because when the page refreshes after adding another item the original one goes away and get's replaced by the most recent entry from the text box.

I am trying to achieve this tactic of trying to either...

**a.** Have a session remember the next item being added EVEN through a page refresh.

or

**b.** Just not refresh the page at all.

See demo here: http://query.notesquare.me/home.html/

**CODE**

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="input-create-playlist" placeholder="Playlist Name" name="create_playlist" />
    <input type="submit" id="button-create-playlist" value="Create Playlist" />
</form>

<?php
    session_start();

    $create_playlist = $_POST['create_playlist'];

    $playlists = array("One", "Two", "Three");

    $_SESSION['main'] = $playlists;

    array_push($playlists, $create_playlist);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($playlists); $i++) {
        echo $playlists[$i] . "<br />";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You need to move up the array_push before setting the $_SESSION variable. And if you want to store more than the last playlist you need to read from the $_SESSION variable, add the new playlist, save to the $_SESSION variable.

Comment: Or just save directly to the session $_SESSION['main'][] = $create_playlist; And use the $_SESSION variable in the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="input-create-playlist" placeholder="Playlist Name" name="create_playlist" />
    <input type="submit" id="button-create-playlist" value="Create Playlist" />
</form>

<?php
    session_start();

    $create_playlist = $_POST['create_playlist'];

    $_SESSION['user_playlists'][] = $create_playlist;

    $playlists = array("One", "Two", "Three");

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['user_playlists']); $i++) {
        array_push($playlists, $_SESSION['user_playlists'][$i]);
    }

    $_SESSION['main'] = $playlists;      

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($playlists); $i++) {
        echo $playlists[$i] . "<br />";
    }
?>
```

Your approach was setting the `$_SESSION['main'] = $_POST['create_playlist']` before the desired effects of `array_push`.

Comment: Ok, it seems that there are problems with the php settings. Could you please some of the session related variables. You could phpinfo() but take this in account: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196011/what-security-problems-could-come-from-exposing-phpinfo-to-end-users

Comment: I printed the settings of my PHP here: http://query.notesquare.me/, Do you think you can help me target the problem? Maybe something is disabled under Sessions or Cookies?

Comment: The problem could be /tmp directory: there might not be writing permissions for the user apache runs as. Do `sudo chmod 775 /tmp`.

Comment: Also check what user apache is running as `lsof -i | less`

Comment: What would I check "sudo chmod 775 /tmp" under, I know there's a TMP file but where would I check for what?

Comment: With `sudo chmod 775 /tmp` you change permission of directory /tmp. Your httpd process user might not have permissions to write to that directory - the user might not be in the group that has write permissions. So with `lsof -i | less` you can check the user and then with `ls -ad /tmp` check the permissions.

Comment: Alright, I changed the permissions to 775 and checked, and they are indeed 775. Although the code is still not working

Comment: What is your httpd user and to what group does the user belong?

Comment: The code was working ever since the second edit, the problem on your side.

Comment: What is the directory for httpd user? and how would I check it?

Comment: httpd is is a process that is owned by some user. By default, if you are using apache, the user would be www-data. And there is no directory (i mean user home directory) for www-data. You have not answered previous comments: check lsof -i | less and ls -ad /tmp !

Comment: Have you any answers yet?

Comment: How do I check it, and where can I check this... I'm absolutely 100% confused as to if this is a "console-like" thing that I can just enter and get data from. I'm using GoDaddy cPanel btw, but it should be there... I just don't know how to find it at all!

Comment: Do you have /tmp directory at all? What are /tmp permissions?

Comment: Yes, there is a tmp directory. Where should I be looking?

Comment: What are the /tmp permissions?

Comment: The permissions for the tmp directory are 775, like you said. I right clicked on it and set the permissions from 755 to 775

Comment: Ok, try to set to to 777.

Comment: Here is my TMP directory and the permissions for the folder, It still doesn't work. http://i.imgur.com/8NehXjn.png

Comment: can you check /var/log/apache2/error.log (the default apahce2 error path for most linux distros)

Comment: Where are the logs saved? Check the log file for errors. Print me the output.

Comment: 눀걞U흍oۆ毽䎱P㻍M഍Ȱᨁq膈"9Ⓔ�⁫KԾj(별Ꮛl繹ܙٝٝ錬㘦*涍νǯB%OoW钒"/䩴뎅*ğѤُӨ鞏篓ˉ䄈䉣ɹ$꼜ϯ먉嬱n闺ꭚ阞D믅ḋ敟卲.龱⃼.۫/㫥"柶،0⯤鿤... Basically... Giberish...

Comment: Ok, try to make 777 (probably, too much) dir and ini_set(session.save_path, '/path/to/your/dir')

Comment: 1. Yes, it can 2. No, make another folder, for example, under the same directory that contains the index.php file

Comment: This is the snippet of code I put before session_start()... `ini_set(session.save_path, "/tmp");`

Comment: No, make another dir, for example, under the same dir that contains the index.php file

Comment: So you want me to make another directory called "tmp" and then inside that tmp directory, create a file called "index.php" which is where I put `ini_set(session.save_path, "/tmp");`?

Comment: You can name it whatever you want to. Are you kidding me?

Comment: Can you just link me a page or stackoverflow to how to do this?

Comment: What is the path to your index.php ? I will write it for you.

Comment: Not how to make linux directory commands, how to properly have sessions stored correctly.

Comment: Next time just use google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604589/how-to-use-session-start-properly-on-godaddy-site

Comment: There is no index.php

Comment: Since you are using Apache/2.4.12 (Unix), then I am asking you what is the DocumentIndex of http://query.notesquare.me/. In a very, very simple way: what is the file that is opened when you go to  http://query.notesquare.me/ ?

Comment: home.html is the file that gets opened.

Comment: Go to the directory where home.html is located. Write down the path to this directory, for example, /var/www/notesquare/. Create a new directory 'sessions'. Write this in the file home.html: ini_set("session.save_path", "/var/www/notesquare/home.html"); before session_start().

Comment: Shouldn't I be saving the sessions to the sessions directory, not back to the home.html? Because essentially what that comment is telling me is... to find the directory of my main home.html in query.notesquare.me and then create a new directory called "sessions" and then inside home.html do the ini_set, which essentially leaves the sessions directory empty.

Comment: You're telling me to create a new directory called 'sessions' but not telling me what to do with it or what to put into it, so I'm just leaving it empty which doesn't seem right...

Comment: It is clearly written there: No such file or directory /public_html/query.notesquare.me/home.html//sess_4fd0jbd03kgboaqsjm5ph54nb. So create directory 'whatever' under /home/kucerajacob/public_html/query.notesquare.me/ like /home/kucerajacob/public_html/query.notesquare.me/whatever and set permissions to 777. Later ini_set("session.save_path", " /home/kucerajacob/public_html/query.notesquare.me/whatever");

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot more sense - I will try it when I get home!

Comment: You deserve way more, I can't upvote because I only have 6 reputation